# How to disable dragndrop for tabpane in Javafx/Tornadofx?

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, tornadofx

My Scene already haves a dragndrop feature but now that I have made the root a TabPane, the TabPane creates a new tab if I drag files into my Program (my dragndrop feature still works). How can I disable this behaivior of the TabPane? I tried to consume the events in the setOnDragDropped and setOnDragOver of the scene but it seems like the events reaches the TabPane before it reaches my Scene.

Update:
I think its not possible for me to close the question (correct me if Im wrong), but I misinterpreted what was going on or what was the mistake, the whole Question was wrong. I solved the real problem with a workaround (by putting tabpane into vbox, so now vbox is the root).

The real problem is this: accesing nodes adds them into other nodes.

```
fun justManipulateNodes(){

someNode.add(...) //This line doesnt only manipulate someNode but it Adds someNode itself to where ever justManipulateNodes() is called. To be concrete, someNode is another vbox in my example and Im adding labels into it

}

override fun onBeforeShow() {
        super.onBeforeShow()

        this.currentStage?.scene?.setOnDragDropped {
            //do other stuff
            justManipulateNodes() //this call ads someNode into the Tabpane as a new Tab if it is the root 
            it.consume()
        }
```

Comment: Minimal example?

Comment: Maybe add code?